# ¿Como puedo hacer que el contenido de checkbox funcione como un item del listview?

Tags: wpf, c#-8.0

No consigo hacer que el contenido del checkbox reaccione al evento chageitemselection de un listview. No se como expresarlo correctamente

`foreach (FileInfo fi in file.GetFiles())
{

```
                CheckBox Casilla = new CheckBox();
                // WrapPanel wrapPanel = new WrapPanel();
                // Image img = new Image();
                //TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
                //img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Imágenes/XML.png"));
                // wrapPanel.Children.Add(img);
                //txt.Text = fi.Name;
                //wrapPanel.Children.Add(txt);
                //Casilla.Content = wrapPanel;


                Casilla.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    //Casilla.Content = wrapPanel;
                 Casilla.Content = fi.Name;
                 Normativas.Items.Add(Casilla.Content);

                }`
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Necesito leer el contenido de un checkbox pero si muestro la casilla de verificación correspondiente no se activa el evento selecteditemchanged de listview. ¿De qué manera construyo el item para poder leer los datos del checkbox seleccionado?

Comment: Creo que algo entiendo de tu pregunta, pero necesito que la aclares, por favor, redacta una pregunta más detallada, paso a paso con lo que haces y dónde es que falla.

Answer (score -2):

En realidad era muy sencillo con xaml

[Utilicé una plantilla para enlazar items y chekbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-listviewitems-with-a-checkbox?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.